# Visual Studio 2019 IntelliSense not recognizing changed value

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

[image]

I have just upgraded from Visual Studio 2017 Community to Visual Studio 2019 Community.  I have an issue with the implementation of Intellisense.

As you can see in the above image of my code, `startingValue` is declared and defined on line 22 with a value of `1.15`.  Immediately above it you can see a commented line wherein it was previously set to `2.0`.

In holding the cursor over `startingValue` on line 27 IntelliSense is showing the value to be `2.0`, the original value.  While the code runs properly with the correct `1.15` value, the incorrect IntelliSense display surprised me.

**I have tried** performing a clean build and physically removing files with this same code from the project, i.e., deleting them from the directory.  Before deleting, these files had been excluded from the project.  These attemptes did not change the situation.

It almost seems as if IntelliSense needs to be updated or "cleaned" when such changes are made.  I do not recall having such issues in VS 2017.

Perhaps there are a number of new setup options for VS 2019 of which I am unaware.

Comment: Well, for what it is worth, changing the value in the commented code changes the IntelliSense display.  When the commented code line is removed IntelliSense shows no value.

Comment: Hi, that's expected behavior. Cause the function is used to display just comments(text), not evaluating the definitions of the variable like what you expected :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.For normal situations, the quick info displays in this format:

[image]

When I hover over the `count` variable, it will only display the type of this variable. But it won't display the value of it.

2.If in some situation, the program would break up if the count's value is too big, we can add a comment for it as a reminder. See:

```
   // Please take care about this value, if it's too big, program will break up! 
    int count = 5;
    int temp = count;
```

For this situation, you'll see the extra content in quick info option.

[image]

See, this's a great option to display comments. You can consider it a reminder, when we use the count variable in line55, or line155... We can see the comment as a reminder to avoid something broken.

> Well, for what it is worth, changing the value in the commented code
>   changes the IntelliSense display. When the commented code line is
>   removed IntelliSense shows no value.

So what you experienced is **expected behavior**(by design) for this option.

It's only used to `display comments for one variable`, `not to display the definitions` of one programming sentence. And that's why if you change value in commented code, then the content in Quick Info changes. Hope it resolves your puzzle :)

**In addition:** For now VS don't provide a option to show value of variable when hovering over it if you're not debugging. And if you're debugging the program, [DataTips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/view-data-values-in-data-tips-in-the-code-editor?view=vs-2019#work-with-datatips) is what you want.